# Nunit test dlls, run separately pass, run together 2nd one fails

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nunit, structuremap

I've got a suite of nunit tests, run in the test runner.

2 separate dlls,

If I run them independently they both work.
If I run them together the second fails.

We are using Structure Map 2.5.3

I've traced the problem down to our NH session lifecycle.

```
     x.BuildInstancesOf<INHFactory>()
                .AddInstances(z => z
                    .OfConcreteType<NHFactory>()
                    .WithName("JCDC")
                )
                .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton);
```

if I run them separately the session is created each time, but if run them together, the same one is reused causing it to crash.

I've tried instance scope thread, no joy, I've tried manually recycling structure map with   ObjectFactory.ResetDefaults(); in my test fixture teardown.

No joy.

Is there a way to force nunit to run them in separate threads? 
or to recycle the structure map factory between dlls (in the tear down in the base test)?

Is there another way to approach this?

Here is the full bootstrap code

```
using System.Reflection;
using JCDCHelper.Logging.Interfaces;
using JCDCHelper.NhAccess.Interfaces;
using JCDCHelper.NhAccess.BusinessObjects;
using JCDCHelper.Persistence.BusinessObjects;
using JCDCHelper.Persistence.Interfaces;
using POCAdmin3G.DAL.Interfaces;
using POCAdmin3G.Jcdc.EO;
using POCAdmin3G.Jcdc.Map;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Attributes;

namespace _Test_DAL
{
    public class _BootstrapStuctureMap
    {
        private static bool _hasStarted;

        /// <summary>
        /// Bootstraps the structure map.
        ///   Set up IOC for all parts of application
        ///   Set up NHFactory for each DB with scope of one per application.
        ///   Set up NHSession for Tran and NoTran.  Give it a scope of HttpRequest or Thread
        /// </summary>
        /// <Author>fink.pete</Author>
        /// <CreateDate>8/31/2010</CreateDate>
        public void BootstrapStructureMap()
        {
            _hasStarted = true;

            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.PullConfigurationFromAppConfig = false;
                x.Scan(y =>
                {
                    y.Assembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IPOCContrCtrlDAL))); // TestDisplay DAL
                    y.Assembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IWebAccess))); // JCDCHelper Persistance
                    y.Assembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(INHSession))); // JCDCHelper NhAccess
                    y.Assembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(INetLog))); // JCDCHelper Logging

                    y.WithDefaultConventions();
                }
                    );

                // needed for new one WebAccess per application
                x.BuildInstancesOf<IWebAccess>()
                  .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<WinFormAccess>()
                  .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid);

                // needed for new one Factory for JCDC per application
                x.BuildInstancesOf<INHFactory>()
                    .AddInstances(z => z
                        .OfConcreteType<NHFactory>()
                        .WithName("JCDC")
                    )
                    .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton);

                // needed for NHSession for JCDC HasTran per HttpRequest
                x.ForRequestedType<INHSession>()
                    .AddInstances(z => z
                        .OfConcreteType<NHSession>()
                        .WithName("JCDC_HasTrans")
                        .SetProperty(y => y.DBNameAndHasTran = "JCDC_HasTrans")
                    )
                    .AddInstances(z => z
                        .OfConcreteType<NHSession>()
                        .WithName("JCDC_HasNoTrans")
                        .SetProperty(y => y.DBNameAndHasTran = "JCDC_HasNoTrans")
                    )
                    .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid);
            });

            //Debug.WriteLine(ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave());
            //ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            // Set up the NhibernateFactories
            INHFactory jcdcFactory = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<INHFactory>("JCDC");
            jcdcFactory.BuildFactoryByConfigFile<AcademicEO, AcademicEOMap>("~/JcdcDb.config");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Restarts StructureMap.   Reset to original defaults.
        /// </summary>
        /// <Author>fink.pete</Author>
        /// <CreateDate>8/31/2010</CreateDate>
        public static void Restart()
        {

            if (_hasStarted)
            {
                ObjectFactory.ResetDefaults();
            }
            else
            {
                Bootstrap();
                _hasStarted = true;
            }
        }

        public static void Bootstrap()
        {
            new _BootstrapStuctureMap().BootstrapStructureMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming use of nunit 2.x, run each assembly in a separate process using the nunit-console option /process:Multiple.